# Named pipe in VB6: CallNamedPipe() failed with error 87

Tags: vb6, message, named-pipes

I am using CallNamedPipe() in VB6 to send messages to a C# named pipe server.
On the server side the pipe is created by:

```
new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads);
```

On the client I use this call to write 2 bytes:

```
  Dim Header(1) As Byte
  Header(0) = 0
  Header(1) = 6
  res = CallNamedPipe(szPipeName, Header(0), 2, bArray(0), numBytes, cbRead, 3000)
```

The server saw the pipe connected because WaitForConnection() did return, but then could not read any bytes.
On the client side: CallNamedPipe failed and returned error code 87 (invalid parameters?)

My questions are:

1. Is the pipe created a byte mode or message mode type? MSDN says CallNamedPipe() fails if the pipe is byte mode.
2. Is there a way to write to a byte mode pipe in VB6. Do I have to change the server code to create a message mode pipe?
3. How to get my VB6 code working?

Comment: Ok, I now know that to create a message type pipe I need another constructor with a PipeTransmissionMode option. I have now got the CallNamedPipe() call working. Moving on to the next problem.

Comment: The error code 87 means "The parameter is incorrect.", according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354762.aspx), the pipe is in byte mode when you use that constructor.  I don't know much about the non-.NET pipe calls, but I don't see any reason why not to set the server to a message mode pipe if the VB6 needs it.

Comment: Well the server is talking to a few other C++ and C# clients in byte mode. In byte mode, I first write the length of the string to the pipe, then write the body of the string. The server will decode the byte stream this way. Now I have to figure out how message mode works.

Comment: @Charlie The `CallNamedPipe` page on MSDN says it is equivalent to calling `CreateFile` plus other methods.  The CreateFile page and its link to a page more about pipes suggests you may be able to do byte mode with VB6, but you will have to call more methods yourself (probably CreateFile, WriteFile, and CloseHandle).

Comment: Gideon, thanks for the info. I found that too, and I'm trying to make this Call working: pipeHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe3", GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, ByVal 0, ByVal 0&, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0). But it gives me "type mismatch" error at this line.

Comment: I made a stupid typo that caused CreateFile not to work. I need to continue to fight with named pipes but I can close this question now. Thank you @Gideon.